# How can a bash code, while it is nested in a third function, do a return completely

Tags: bash, function

How can a bash code do a return completely (as if it returns from main function) when it is being in a third nested function call, in order to get back to shell prompt at once ?

the main function invocation is one which will fully shut down terminal if `exit` command is given.
tried so many times in vain, one of them:

```
c(){
local p
#...

[ "$p" = err ] && kill $TID

#...
}

b(){
#...
c
#...
}

a(){
export TID=$$
#...

b
#...
#...
}
```

Comment: Use `exit` instead of `return`.

Comment: based solely on the sample script ... killing the current PID (TID == $$) ... should return you to the command prompt rather quickly, yes?

Comment: Your Q isn't completely clear (to me). But you write *"will fully shut down terminal if exit command is given"*, and I take that to mean that your terminal is disappearing when it hits an `exit` command. This would normally only happen if you are declaring your functions from the cmd-line OR sourcing your function defintion files, i.e. `. /path/to/myFuncLibrary`. If you wrap you sourcing of functions in a shell script, and run that, then you are lauching a sub-shell to your terminal, and when that exits, you are retured to the cmd-line. Good luck.

Comment: you could also continue as you are, but first typing `bash` to lauch a sub-shell to your terminal session. That will consume the exit, but each time you want to load/run the functions and use them, you'll need to be in a sub-shell. Also you may need to reinvoke $HOME/.bash_rc or others to have a comparable shell environment. Good luck.